# Moving in a .txt

Tags: c++, stream, ostream

I'm currently working on a bomberman game :D. Its going on pretty damn well honestly. I'm now creating my map editor but I would like to know if its possible to move throught a .txt file using an out stream ? I have already learned how to read using a buffer (String)

```
while (courant2 != NULL) //I EST LA HAUTEUR
{
    courant1=courant2;
    LeVectorPosition.x = 0;
    while (courant1 != NULL) //J EST LA LONGEUR
    {
        Fichier >> buffer;
```

As you can see, I use this buffer to move around each word and I was suprise when I saw that it moved over space by itself. Now though, I want to move inside my .txt file to then change a tile.

0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,1-Y 0,1-N
0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,1-Y 0,1-N
0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,1-Y 0,1-N
0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,1-Y 0,1-N
0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,1-Y 0,1-N
0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,0-N 0,1-Y 0,1-N

Would someone mind explaining to me the basic of moving and using an Ostream ? It would be really appreciate. Thank you and sorry for my miserable english XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ostream::seekp` to move the stream position backward or forward, as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/)

Comment: By stream, do you mean like each word ? Or like each space ? Additionnaly, do you know how to change the next letter ?

Comment: The position is moved in number of characters. ostream is an outputstream, so it can be used to write to the streambuffer passed in parameter of the constructor, not to read. If you want to change the next letter, you can first call `seekp` to go to the desired position in the file, then use the `<<` operator to write the character